# Set_xlabel is in invalid in ax[0, 0] when drawing 4 subplots in one plot

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I get some codes as followed and I want to draw 4 subplots in one plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

# ax[0, 0]
sns.countplot(train_df['Survived'], ax=ax[0, 0])
ax[0, 0].set_xlabel('Survived')

# ax[0, 1]
ax[0, 1].pie(train_df['Survived'].value_counts(), autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax[0, 1].set_aspect('equal')
ax[0, 1].set_xlabel('Survived')

# ax[1, 0]
sns.countplot(train_df['Pclass'].values, ax=ax[1, 0])
ax[1, 0].set_xlabel('Pclass')

# ax[1, 1]
ax[1, 1].pie(train_df['Pclass'].value_counts(), autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax[1, 1].set_aspect('equal')
ax[1, 1].set_xlabel('Pclass')

plt.savefig('four_subplots_in_one_figure.jpg')
```

[image: a]

But what I find is that I the **first subplot** in `ax[0,0]` doesn't have an x_label even if I have set it on purpose.
The data I use is from [Titanic in Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic).
So if not mind could anyone tell me how to set it right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xlabel` is simply hidden under the bottom plot.
You can use [`plt.tight_layout()`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html?highlight=tight) at the end of your script to automatically adjust the sizes of each subplots to see their respective labels.